# TableColumn setPreferredWidth not working

Tags: java, swing, resize, jtable

I have a JTable with a number of columns. I want a particular column to resize. What I was hoping was by using setPreferredWidth, the column would resize to that size, or the size of the contents such that **no truncation occurred** and let the rest of the columns take the remaining space, but instead, all of the columns, including the one I resized, equally split all of the space of the table; as if setPreferredWidth did **nothing at all**. In effect, I want to be able to set the width of a column and have it shrink to that size **without truncating content** (have I stressed that too much yet?) in such a way that all columns that have not been resized fill the remaining space. Using setMaxWidth truncates content (did I mention I didn't like that?) How do I resize/shrink a column without it truncating and without it doing **absolutely nothing**? Here is the offending code:

```
for (int i = 0, x = 0; i < table.getColumnModel().getColumnCount(); i++)
    if ((x = model.getColumnWidth(i)) > -1)
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setPreferredWidth(x);
```

The table is in a JPanel (MyListPanel - BorderLayout) which is in another JPanel (GridBagLayout) added with:

```
new GridBagConstraints(0, 3, 1, 1, 1.0, 0.0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, new Insets(2, 0, 0, 2), 0, 0))
```

EDIT: This is the constructor for my subclass of JPanel:

```
public MyListPanel(boolean showHeader, String title, ColData...columns) {
    super(new BorderLayout());
    model = new MyListTableModel(columns);
    table = new JTable(model);

    table.addFocusListener(this);

    add(table);
    table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);

    setTitle(title);

    if (showHeader)
        add(table.getTableHeader(), BorderLayout.NORTH);

    for (int i = 0, x = 0; i < table.getColumnModel().getColumnCount(); i++)
        if ((x = model.getColumnWidth(i)) > -1)
            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setPreferredWidth(x);

    setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.LOWERED));
}
```

And MyListTableModel.ColData:

```
public static class ColData {
    private int index;
    private String title;
    private int width;
    public ColData(int _index, String _title, int _width) { index = _index; title = _title; width = _width; }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Include :

```
table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
```

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem despite trying the two other answers here.  In my case, some times the width would get set correctly while other times, it would not.  I found the problem was caused because I was trying to set the column widths immediately after changing my table model.  I found setting the column widths inside of SwingUtilities.invokeLater() did the trick.  I.E.

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

    @Override
    public void run() {
         int width = 100;  
         for (int column = 1; column < table.getColumnCount(); column++) {
             columnModel.getColumn(column).setPreferredWidth(width);
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm going to upvote you because this seems like it might have fixed my problem, but I quit that job.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a bit late so is mostly for future readers, but I had the same problem and solved it by setting both the column's **preferred width** and **maximum width** to the same value.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and reading @Jay Askren answer, the opposite worked for me. I had to set the width in the method where the table was being created.

```
public class Example{
    //..stuff
    private JTable myTable;

    public Example{
    //..stuff
    myTable = AnotherClass.getTable();
    myTable .getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(100);//not here
    }

}

public class AnotherClass{
    public static JTable getTable(){
    JTable table= new JTable();
    table.setModel(anyModel);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(100);//Here!
    return table
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set all three of setMinWidth, setMaxWidth and setPreferredWidth, where minimum_width <= preferred_width <= maximum_width.

```
        int[] minColSizes       = { 15,  55,  75,  50,  50,  50 };
        int[] preferredColSizes = { 25,  75, 125, 100, 100, 100 };
        int[] maxSizes          = { 50, 100, 200, 200, 200, 200 };
        for ( int index = 0; index < preferredColSizes.length; index++ )
        {
            myTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(index).setMinWidth ( minColSizes[index] );
            myTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(index).setMaxWidth ( preferredColSizes[index] + 100 );
            myTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(index).setPreferredWidth ( maxSizes[index] );
        }
```